# MAX Grouping by 2 columns

Tags: sql, max

I'm stumped as in how to do this.

I have 3 columns the first is a parent company, second is the child and the third is it's revenue. I want to find out which child per parent has the most revenue and what that revenue is.

So like the below

```
Vodafone.      Argentina.      5b 
Vodafone.      Spain.          4b 
Vodafone.      England.        10b
```

So the answer would be

```
Vodafone.      England          10b
```

Apologies for the formatting, on my phone.

Comment: Have you even tried anything???

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, what do you want when there are ties?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()`. Here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iQxLCVxrVMtANUrPsgpx6U/1).

```
select
  company, 
  child,
  revenue
from
(
  select
    *,
    row_number() over (partition by company order by cast(revenue as int) desc) as rn
  from yourTable
) subq
where rn = 1
```

output:

```
| company  | child   | revenue |
| -------- | ------- | ------- |
| Vodafone | England | 10      |
```

You can use `dense_rank()` if more than one company have same revenue.

Comment: You need to add a partition by clause for the company

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below one -

```
select * from tablename 
where cast(revenue as int) = (select max(cast(revenue as int)) from tablename)
```